# label2rgb implementation for OpenCV

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

Does OpenCV have function that can visualise a `Mat` of labels? Ie, similar o matlabs `label2rgb()`.

The closest I can find is: `cv2.applyColorMap(cv2.equalizeHist(segments), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)`

However this is not a desired method when doing segmentation of video where the number of labels changes from one frame to the next. The reason being; one frame will have 2 labels (0 and 1 - representing sky and ground) so using jet it might show those 2 segments as dark blue and red respectively. The next frame has 3 labels (0,1,2 - sky, ground and car), so the ground segment has now change colour from red to yellow. So when you visualise this the same segments keeps changing colour and not remaining a consistent colour (red).

Therefore a function like matlabs `label2rbg()` would be really useful if it exists?

Comment: You can threshold your image if needed, then use contours or blobs and connected components to get and label each isolated region. Check the documentation for those terms.

Comment: Remove the call to `cv2.equalizeHist`, then the labels won't jump around. And then you should find a better color map that distinguishes consecutive labels (such as the one I use [here](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/8dd5ab71e8f7110f2b484982fa93d4d2ed21d2aa/src/display/colormap.cpp#L560)).

Answer (score 4):

I like to use `cv2.LUT` for when there are less than 256 labels (since it only works with `uint8`).  If you have more than 256 labels you can always convert to 256 values using `(labels % 256).astype(np.uint8)`.

Then with your labels you simply call: `rgb = cv2.LUT(labels, lut)`.

The only remaining problem is to create a lookup-table (`lut`) for your labels. You can use matplotlib colormaps as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

def label2rgb(labels):
  """
  Convert a labels image to an rgb image using a matplotlib colormap
  """
  label_range = np.linspace(0, 1, 256)
  lut = np.uint8(plt.cm.viridis(label_range)[:,2::-1]*256).reshape(256, 1, 3) # replace viridis with a matplotlib colormap of your choice
  return cv2.LUT(cv2.merge((labels, labels, labels)), lut)
```

For many cases it is better to have the colors of adjacent labels be wildly different. Rick Szelski gives a pseudo code to achieve this in his [book](http://szeliski.org/Book/drafts/SzeliskiBook_20100903_draft.pdf), appendix C2: Pseudocolor Generation.  I've worked with his algorithm and variants of it in the past, it is fairly straightforward to code something up.  Here is an sample code using his algorithm:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


def gen_lut():
  """
  Generate a label colormap compatible with opencv lookup table, based on
  Rick Szelski algorithm in `Computer Vision: Algorithms and Applications`,
  appendix C2 `Pseudocolor Generation`.
  :Returns:
    color_lut : opencv compatible color lookup table
  """
  tobits = lambda x, o: np.array(list(np.binary_repr(x, 24)[o::-3]), np.uint8)
  arr = np.arange(256)
  r = np.concatenate([np.packbits(tobits(x, -3)) for x in arr])
  g = np.concatenate([np.packbits(tobits(x, -2)) for x in arr])
  b = np.concatenate([np.packbits(tobits(x, -1)) for x in arr])
  return np.concatenate([[[b]], [[g]], [[r]]]).T

def labels2rgb(labels, lut):
  """
  Convert a label image to an rgb image using a lookup table
  :Parameters:
    labels : an image of type np.uint8 2D array
    lut : a lookup table of shape (256, 3) and type np.uint8
  :Returns:
    colorized_labels : a colorized label image
  """
  return cv2.LUT(cv2.merge((labels, labels, labels)), lut)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  labels = np.arange(256).astype(np.uint8)[np.newaxis, :]
  lut = gen_lut()
  rgb = labels2rgb(labels, lut)
```

And here is the colormap:

[image]

Comment: Of course Szeliski has that in the appendix! I [answered OPs question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/opencv/comments/ce8cwz/question_label2rgb_implementation_for_opencv/eu0vgli/) suggesting to use the golden ratio (golden angle) for hue values to map, so that each successive label is nearly "maximally different" in hue from the previous ones. I like my approach too, but damn flipping the bits is such a nice idea!